# Spring Boot "Could not resolve placeholder"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot Tomcat application using Maven. When I run it in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) it works fine. However when I run it normally

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I get an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'sysm.client.api.path' in value "${sysm.client.api.path}"
```

I also tried using JarLoader and PropertiesLauncher with no better luck.

I do have that property sysm.client.api.path defined in my application.properties, but for good measure I also added it to the command line as a -D parameter -Dsysm.client.api.path=my-path.

The Value injection itself is happening in some dependency code, otherwise I would simply hard code that value.

One note: IntelliJ is not running it as a -jar; rather it declares all of the libraries in a vast -classpath command line argument and then uses my @SpringBootApplication class as the executable class, completely not in keeping with the Spring Boot spirit!

I am wondering why this module seems to be getting its properties before the application.properties are loaded, and if there is any way to resequence that so that it works

UPDATE: I double checked the jar and the application properties are there under BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties. But for some reason the application is not seeing that in the jar. When I copy those to the launch dir, it works fine. Not sure why these are not being picked up from the jar as expected?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>commy-group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <distribution.root>discovery-service-${project.version}</distribution.root>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <ansible.group>npc</ansible.group>
    <ansible.name>${project.artifactId}</ansible.name>
    <ansible.deploy>2018-1</ansible.deploy>
</properties>

<scm>
    <url>..</url>
    <connection>..</connection>
    <developerConnection>..</developerConnection>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    ...
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ********************* SPRING ********************* -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <shortRevisionLength>8</shortRevisionLength>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: looks it's missing defined your appplication.properties in /src/main/resources who has sysm.client.api.path proeprty

Comment: I don't think so. The properties are there, and I also added the missing property to the command line just for safe keeping (and I also copied the entire application.properties to the file system alongside the launcher). The application.properties are there, just that it seems to be resolving that bean before the application.properties are loaded

Comment: Do you use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to generate the fatjar? Can you check your jar whether it has the application.properties included?

Comment: So can you add your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, these are definitely in the jar:
-bash-4.1$ jar -tf lib/myjar.jar|grep application.properties
BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties

Comment: I just noticed that when I copy the application.properties to the application root, it works correctly. For some reason it is not seeing that file in the jar

Comment: Have you tried mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage ?

Comment: I am doing a mvn clean deploy on the build server. I added the pom above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. We have a custom deployer that deploys all of the jars for a general Java application. Of course this is not necessary for a SpringBoot application, since all of the jars are internal (except for the main jar and the -bootstrapper.jar), but I would expect it not to hurt the execution of the application.

However when I deleted all of the superfluous jars, the application suddenly started recognizing the embedded application.properties.

I am tempted to close this question, but perhaps it might be relevant to people who have the same situation? Also, I would like to understand why this behavior occurs? (It only happens with some applications. Others work fine with the superfluous jars)

Comment: some of those jars presumably had sysm.client.api.path = "value" in them?

Comment: Yes presumably they do, thank you very much. Please make it an answer and I will mark it correct